# Show path of library that ld found through -l

Tags: c++, c, libraries

Is it possible to make g++/ld show the absolute path of the library, that a -l option has been resolved to?
In my case I am trying to link the lrs library through -llrs and I suspect that it resolves to /usr/lib/liblrs.so but I want to be sure.

Comment: That only shows include paths, not library paths. However, a similiar method to show library paths would only list all candidates, not the actual resolution.

Comment: `ldd foo` shows the runtime resolution of the library, if that helps you.

Comment: If linking using `g++` you might want to try `-Wl,--verbose` .

Answer (score 1):

ELF files do not include an absolute path to the shared library. That is the job of the dynamic linker. You can confirm this by running. strings executable | grep libname. The shared library can be anywhere on the linker search path.

readelf -d executable

To test the behaviour of the dynamic loader use ldd (List Dynamic Dependencies)

Example below with /bin/bash

> ldd /bin/bash
>
> libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

You may also want to follow symlinks

> ls -al /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Feb  5  2019 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.23.so